# Link boost to qt creator

Tags: c++, qt, boost, qt-creator

I have a problem. I built MongoDB driver (with msvc14) and connected it to qt creator. But it needs boost library. And then I added it to my .pro file it showed me an error:

```
E:\Projects\qt\mngProj\mng_driver\include\bsoncxx\v_noabi\bsoncxx\stdx\string_view.hpp:37: error: C1083: Cannot open file: boost/utility/string_ref.hpp: No such file or directory
```

I tried to locate header files and to build boost and locate library from system directory and to locate all libraries from ".../stage/lib". But nothing happened. My .pro file:

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-02-10T12:18:47
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = mngProj
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui


#LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/stage/lib
#LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/mng_driver/lib/ -llibbsoncxx
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/mng_driver/lib/ -llibbsoncxxd

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/ -llibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59d

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/liblibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.a
else:win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/liblibboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59d.a
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59.lib
else:win32:!win32-g++:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../local/boost_1_59_0/bin.v2/libs/system/build/msvc-14.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/libboost_system-vc140-mt-gd-1_59d.lib
```

Comment: First of all, that is not a linker error. Add an include path to boost.

Comment: A clean, run qmake, and rebuild usually fixes these issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is solved.
I dont know why, but you need to delete build folder manually, and I passed link stage with that .pro file:

```
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lbson-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lbson-static-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lmongoc-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lmongoc-static-1.0
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lbsoncxx
LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -lmongocxx

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libbson-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/mng_driver/include/libmongoc-1.0

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/include/mongocxx/v_noabi

INCLUDEPATH += E:/local/boost_1_59_0/
DEPENDPATH += E:/local/boost_1_59_0/

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -llibbsoncxx

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/libbsoncxx.lib

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/ -llibmongocxx

win32-g++:CONFIG(release, debug|release): PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$PWD/../../../mongo-c-driver/lib/libmongocxx.lib
```